How do I get drift-free, parallax mapping using position maps so I can stack decals on decals using a simple algorithm?
How do I get drift-free, parallax mapping using position maps, so I can stack decals on decals using a simple algorithm?

Here is the solution. If you're using Blender 4.x series, you may have to update to avoid a color management bug that is breaking 16bpp & 32bpp image textures. If the stacked decals are drifting then either use a gamma node to correct it or just go back to Blender 3x series for now.





